# Get parent(key) from value (an element stored in a list)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am stuck in a problem wherein I have to find the common 'parent' of items in a list.

Here's the problem-

I have a reference file - `hierarchy.json`, and this file is loaded as a dictionary in my super class.

```
{
    "DATE": ["ISO", "SYSTEM", "HTTP"],
    "IP": ["IPv4", "IPv6"],
    "PATH": ["UNIX", "WINDOWS"]
}
```

As an input, I get a `list` of values and I expect to get a set of elements, **which belong to the same parent (referring to the `hierarchy.json` file)** as an output. Even better, if I could get the parent name, that would be great.

```py
input_list = ["ISO", "UNIX", "HTTP"]

result = do_something(input_list)

print('RESULT:\t', result)

>>> RESULT:    set("ISO","HTTP")
```

Essentially, I want to make sets of the elements which belong to different "parents" in the element.

I know this can be done `O(n^3)` by looping through each element of the list. This is **obviously** not the best way to achieve the result.

Here's what I have tried -

```py
def do_something(input_list: list, reference_dir: dict) -> list:
    result_list = []
    for lists in reference_dir.values():
        results = []
        for i in input_list:
            for j in input_list:
                if i != j:
                    if set([i,j]).issubset(set(lists)):
                        results.extend(set([i,j]))
        result_list.append(set(results))
    return result_list

input_list = ["ISO", "UNIX", "HTTP", "SYSTEM","WINDOWS"]
reference_dir = {"DATE": ["ISO", "SYSTEM", "HTTP"],"IP": ["IPv4", "IPv6"],"PATH":["UNIX", "WINDOWS"]}

result = do_something(input_list, reference_dir)
print('RESULT:\t', (result))

>>> RESULT:  [{'SYSTEM', 'HTTP', 'ISO'}, set(), {'UNIX', 'WINDOWS'}]
```

Is there a way to optimize this/implement this in a better way?

Edited (Added) ->

ALSO,

if there's a way I could get the name of the 'parent' as the output, that would be AWESOME.

```py
>>> RESULT:  [DATE, PATH]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def do_something(input_list: list, reference_dir: dict) -> list:
    sets_1 = {k: set() for k in reference_dir.keys()}
    sets_2 = {item: sets_1[k] for k, list in reference_dir.items() for item in list}
    for input in input_list:
        sets_2[input].add(input)
    return sets_1

reference_dir = {
    "DATE": ["ISO", "SYSTEM", "HTTP"],
    "IP": ["IPv4", "IPv6"],
    "PATH": ["UNIX", "WINDOWS"]
}

input_list = ["ISO", "UNIX", "HTTP"]

print(do_something(input_list, reference_dir))
```

Prints:

```
{'DATE': {'HTTP', 'ISO'}, 'IP': set(), 'PATH': {'UNIX'}}
```

What do_something does:

1. `sets_1 = {k: set() for k in reference_dir.keys()}` This line creates a dictionary where each key is a key form `reference_dir` and the value is an empty set.
2. `sets_2 = {item: sets_1[k] for k, list in reference_dir.items() for item in list}` This line creates another dictionary. The keys are the elements of the lists which are the values of the reference_dir dictionary and the value for each key is the corresponding empty set created in step 1 associated with the lists owning key.
3. `for input in input_list: sets_2[input].add(input)` Each element of input_list is added to appropriate set using the dictionary created in step 2 to select the correct set.
4. `return sets_1` This returns a dictionary whose keys are all the keys in reference_dir and whose values are now the filled in sets (some of which might be empty). The keys are the "names" of the sets you were looking for.

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/PppA2R)

Comment: Thanks @Ronald for your answer. I will try this out and then mark it as correct.